# 2.3 Scala Play framework - Parse Json with embedded objects

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

the below code gives a compile error of

```
No implicit Reads for controllers.Inner available.
```

If I change

```
case class Outer (in : Inner)
```

to

```
case class Outer (in : String)
```

it'll compile fine, and I can parse both `Outer` and `Inner` json.

What is the best way to parse JSON with embedded object?

```
case class Outer (in : Inner)
object Outer {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Outer]
}


case class Inner (deep: String)
object Inner {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Inner]
}


object Test extends Controller {
  def tester = Action {
    implicit request =>


      val json = request.body.asJson.getOrElse(throw new InvalidRequest("No JSON found in request"))
      val validatedJSON = json.validate[Inner]


      Ok("")


  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is important.

```
case class Inner (deep: String)
object Inner {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Inner]
}

case class Outer (in : Inner)
object Outer {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Outer]
}

object Test extends Controller {
  def tester = Action {
    implicit request =>

      val json = request.body.asJson.getOrElse(throw new InvalidRequest("No JSON found in request"))
      val validatedJSON = json.validate[Inner]

      Ok("")

  }
}
```